# Access denied to database table for MySQL/PHP code

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I am new to PHP and MySQL, but not coding in general.  I am attempting to migrate an Access database into MySQL.

I get the following error after submitting my form information and trying to add a record to the table:

Access denied for user ''@'localhost' to database 'FltLogbook'

In order for the form to build, I access the database to pull out certain values for drop down menus.  All of that works fine.  After clicking the "Add Entry" button and using the Post method, the above error is shown.

I am very confused since previous queries ran just fine, but once I try to "add" the record, I get the error.  The above error appears to be an anonymous connection.  FWIW, the Username I connect with has all priviledges to the database.  I have tried adding records with that username inside the form building portion of the code and was successful.  You will see in the code below I have commented out my actual Insert code. I was troubleshooting data types and trying to simplify the insert command to eliminate other fields causing the error.  The current insert command code works fine in the form building portion of the code, so I know I have the correct code, now I just to solve the connection issue.

After much searching on this site and google, most of the responses to the above error usually involve granting user permissions.  I don't think that is the problem here since I can add a record inside the form building portion of the code.  It appears I go from being an authenticated user to anonymous since no username is not passed in the error.  I used connection_status() in both parts of the code and it returns 0 (Normal).

Any help is certainly appreciated.  Cheers, Heed

Code:

```
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", $_POST[user], $_POST[password], "FltLogbook");

if ($_POST[op] != "add") {
    //Form not shown, show it
    $display="<h1>Add Logbook Entry</h1>";
    $CnxSt = connection_status();
    $display .= "Connection Status: $CnxSt<br><br>";
    $display .= "
    <form method=\"post\" action=\"$_SERVER[PHP_SELF]\">
    <strong>Details:</strong>
    <table border=\"1\" width=\"520\">
    <tr>
    <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"Sim\">Simulator</td>
    <td colspan=\"2\">SimType: <select name=\"SimType\">
    <option value=\"\">  NA </option>
    <option value=\"Miltary Visual\"> Military Visual </option>
    <option value=\"Military Non-Visual\"> Military Non-Visual </option>
    <option value=\"ATD\"> ATD </option>
    <option value=\"FTD\"> FTD </option>
    <option value=\"FFS\"> FFS </option></select></td>
   </tr>
   <tr>
    <td>Date: <input type=\"date\" name=\"FltDate\"></td>
    <td>Aircraft: <select name=\"Aircraft\">
    <option selected=\"selected\" value=\"26\">C-172M</option>";

      $AcftQuery="SELECT Aircraft.AirKey,Aircraft.Aircraft, Aircraft.ME, Aircraft.Complex, Aircraft.HighPerf 
                  FROM Aircraft";
      $AcftResult=mysqli_query($conn, $AcftQuery) or die ("Aircraft Query Failed");
      While ($AcftRow=mysqli_fetch_array($AcftResult)) {
        $AcftKey=$AcftRow['AirKey'];
        $AcftAircraft=$AcftRow['Aircraft'];
        $AcftME=$AcftRow['ME'];
        $AcftComplex=$AcftRow['Complex'];
        $AcftHP=$AcftRow['HighPerf'];
        $display .= "<option value=\"$AcftKey\"> $AcftAircraft </option>";
      }

    $display .= "
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>Aircraft ID: <input type=\"text\" name=\"ID\" size=\"8\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>From: <select name=\"From\">
    <option selected=\"selected\" value=\"PVG\">PVG</option>";

      $ArfldQuery="SELECT AirfieldID FROM Airfields ORDER BY AirfieldID";
      $ArfldResult=mysqli_query($conn, $ArfldQuery) or die ("Airfield Query Failed");
      While ($ArfldRow=mysqli_fetch_array($ArfldResult)) {
        $Arfld=$ArfldRow['AirfieldID'];
        $display .= "<option value=\"$Arfld\"> $Arfld </option>";
      }

    $display .= "
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>To: <select name=\"To\">
    <option selected=\"selected\" value=\"PVG\">PVG</option>";

      $ArfldQuery="SELECT AirfieldID FROM Airfields ORDER BY AirfieldID";
      $ArfldResult=mysqli_query($conn, $ArfldQuery) or die ("Airfield Query Failed");
      While ($ArfldRow=mysqli_fetch_array($ArfldResult)) {
        $Arfld=$ArfldRow['AirfieldID'];
        $display .= "<option value=\"$Arfld\"> $Arfld </option>";
      }

    $display .= "
    </select>
    </td>
    <td>Leg: <select name=\"Leg\">
      <option value=\"1\">1</option>
      <option value=\"2\">2</option>
      <option value=\"3\">3</option>
      <option value=\"4\">4</option>
      <option value=\"5\">5</option>
      <option value=\"6\">6</option>
      </select>
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table><br>
    <strong>Flight Time Info:</strong>
    <table border=\"1\" width=\"520\">
    <tr>
    <td>TPT: <input type=\"text\" name=\"TPT\" size=\"4\"></td>
    <td>PIC: <input type=\"text\" name=\"PIC\" size=\"4\"></td>
    <td>SIC: <input type=\"text\" name=\"SIC\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Solo: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Solo\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    <td colspan=\"2\">Dual Received: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Dual\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Cross Country: <input type=\"text\" name=\"XC\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"FARXCntry\" size=\"4\">FAR X-Cntry</td>
    <td><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"ATPXCntry\" size=\"4\">ATP X-Cntry</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Single Engine: <input type=\"text\" name=\"SE\" size=\"4\"></td>
    <td>Multiengine: <input type=\"text\" name=\"ME\" size=\"4\"></td>
    <td>Night: <input type=\"text\" name=\"NT\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Complex: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Complex\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    <td colspan=\"2\">High Performance: <input type=\"text\" name=\"HP\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Instrument: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Inst\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    <td colspan=\"2\">Sim Instrument: <input type=\"text\" name=\"SimInst\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Instructor: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Instructor\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    <td>Pre-Post: <input type=\"text\" name=\"PrePost\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    <td>Ground: <input type=\"text\" name=\"Ground\" value=\"0.0\" size=\"4\"></td>
    </tr>
    </table><br>
    <strong>Actual Approaches:</strong>
    <table border=\"1\" width=\"520\">
    <tr>
    <td>Precision: <input type=\"text\" name=\"PrecAct\" value=\"0\" size=\"3\"></td>
    <td>Non-Precision: <input type=\"text\" name=\"NonPrecAct\" value=\"0\" size=\"3\"></td>
    </tr>
    </table><br>
    <strong>Simulated Approaches:</strong>
    <table border=\"1\" width=\"520\">
    <tr>
    <td>Precision: <input type=\"text\" name=\"PrecSim\" value=\"0\" size=\"3\"></td>
    <td>Non-Precision: <input type=\"text\" name=\"NonPrecSim\" value=\"0\" size=\"3\"></td>
    </tr>
    </table><br>
    <strong>Landings:</strong>
    <table border=\"1\" width=\"520\">
    <tr>
    <td>Day Landings: <input type=\"text\" name=\"DayLdg\" size=\"3\"></td>
    <td>Night Landings: <input type=\"text\" name=\"NtLdg\" size=\"3\"></td>
    </tr>
    </table><br>
    <strong>Remarks:</strong><br>
    <textarea name=\"Remarks\" rows=\"5\" cols=\"70\"></textarea>
    <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"op\" value=\"add\">
    <p><input type=\"submit\" name=\"submit\" value=\"Add Entry\"></p>
    </FORM>";

} else if ($_POST[op] == "add") {

if ($_POST[Sim] == "") {
    $_POST[Sim] = "0";
} else {
    $_POST[Sim] = "1";
}

if ($_POST[FARXCntry] == "") {
    $_POST[FARXCntry] = "0";
} else {
    $_POST[FARXCntry] = "1";
}

if ($_POST[ATPXCntry] == "") {
    $_POST[ATPXCntry] = "0";
} else {
    $_POST[ATPXCntry] = "1";
}

//  $add_flt = "INSERT INTO FlightData (Date, MakeModel, AircraftID, Simulator, SimType, AfldFrom, AfldTo,
//              Leg, TPT, PIC, SIC, Solo, Dual, Night, XCntry, SE, ME, Complex, HighPerf, Inst_Act, Inst_Sim,
//              Instructor, PrePost, Ground, Prec_Act, Prec_Sim, NonPrec_Act, NonPrec_Sim, DCL, NCL, 
//              FAR_XCntry, ATP_XCntry, Remarks)
//              VALUES ('$_POST[FltDate]', '$_POST[Aircraft]', '$_POST[ID],$_POST[Sim]', '$_POST[SimType]', '$_POST[From]',
//                      '$_POST[To]', '$_POST[Leg]', '$_POST[TPT]', '$_POST[PIC]', '$_POST[SIC]', '$_POST[Solo]', '$_POST[Dual]',
//                      '$_POST[NT]', '$_POST[XC]', '$_POST[SE]', '$_POST[ME]', '$_POST[Complex]', '$_POST[HP]', '$_POST[Inst]',
//                      '$_POST[SimInst]', '$_POST[Instructor]', '$_POST[PrePost]', '$_POST[Ground]', '$_POST[PrecAct]',
//                      '$_POST[PrecSim]', '$_POST[NonPrecAct]', '$_POST[NonPreSim]', '$_POST[DayLdg]', '$_POST[NtLdg]',
//                      '$_POST[FARXCntry]', '$_POST[ATPXCntry]', '$_POST[Remarks]')";

$add_flt = "INSERT INTO FlightData (Date, MakeModel) VALUES ('$_POST[FltDate]', '$_POST[Aircraft]')";

mysqli_query($conn, $add_flt) or die('Error: '. mysqli_connect_error());

$display = "<h1>Entry Added</h1>
<p>Your entry was added.</p><br>
<p>$_POST[FltDate] | $_POST[Aircraft] </p>";

//  $CnxSt = connection_status();
//  $display .= "Connection Status: $CnxSt<br><br>";

//  $display .= "$user / $pwd<br>$add_flt<br>"; 
//  $display .= "$_POST[FltDate] / $_POST[Aircraft] / $_POST[ID] / $_POST[Sim] / $_POST[FARXCntry] / $_POST[ATPXCntry]";

}

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Add Logbook Entry></title>
</head>
<body>
<?php echo $display; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Seems like $_POST[user] is returning null value. BTW, dont we use $POST['user'] instead of $_POST[user]?

Answer (score -1):

You must check your mysql username and password on line 1

if username="root" & password is null then

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "FltLogbook");